# UPDATE a una tabla con valores de un array

Tags: php, mysql, update

Recibo estos `array` de tres `input`, cada `input` tiene su `name` de esta manera: `nombre_pax[ ]` - `tipo_id[ ]` - `rut_pax[ ]`

Lo que pasa al ejecutar el `update`, es que sólo modifica un registro en la tabla, el cual es el último del `array`.

```js
 ["nombre_pax"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(16) "Ricardo Sánchez"
    [1]=>
    string(12) "Pedro Pérez"
  }
  ["tipo_id"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "RUT:"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "RUT: "
  }
  ["rut_pax"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(14) " 30.686.957-4"
    [1]=>
    string(12) "30.686.957-5"
  }
```

```html
  foreach (array_keys($_POST['nombre_pax']) as $key) {
    $nombre_pax = $_POST['nombre_pax'][$key];
    $tipo_id = $_POST['tipo_id'][$key];
    $rut_pax = $_POST['rut_pax'][$key];
    $doc_id = $tipo_id.$rut_pax;

    $query = "UPDATE pax SET nombre='$nombre_pax', doc_id='$doc_id'
              WHERE nro_comprobante='$nro_comprobante'";
    mysqli_query($conexion,$query) or die("NO SE PUDO ACTUALIZAR LA TABLA PAX" . mysqli_error($conexion));
  }
```

Comment: Prueba declarando el `query` antes y fuera del ciclo `foreach`

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con esto:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['nombre_pax']);$i++)
{
    $nombre_pax = $_POST['nombre_pax'][$i];
    $tipo_id = $_POST['tipo_id'][$i];
    $rut_pax = $_POST['rut_pax'][$i];
    $doc_id = $tipo_id.$rut_pax;

    $query = "UPDATE pax SET nombre='$nombre_pax', doc_id='$doc_id'
              WHERE nro_comprobante='$nro_comprobante'";
    mysqli_query($conexion,$query) or die("NO SE PUDO ACTUALIZAR LA TABLA PAX" . mysqli_error($conexion));
}
```

No entiendo muy bien de donde sacas la variable $nro_comprobante, yo lo que haría sería crear un input hidden con la id que tienes que modificar poniéndole el nombre igual que a las demás con [], en el valor la id a modificar y usa esa variable $_POST igual que con las demás, debería funcionar sin problemas.